# Desactivar celda

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy tratando de borrar o guardar la información de una celda usando Apps Script, sin embargo, cuando la celda queda activa, no guarda o borra la información de esa celda,  ¿Cómo hago para desactivar la celda?, o ¿Cómo soluciono este inconveniente?

Cuando las celdas están desactivadas funciona correctamente la función

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
function Limpiar(){
  var Hoja_Calculo = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();//Obtener hoja de calculo
  var Nombre_Hoja = Hoja_Calculo.getActiveSheet().getName();//Obtener nombre de una hoja
  var Hoja_Activa = Hoja_Calculo.getSheetByName(Nombre_Hoja);//Traer la hoja en la que se esta trabajando
  var rango_limpiar = ["E8", "E10", "E12", "E14", "E16", "E18", "E20"];

 //falta algo para cambiar el foco de la celda o desactivar el cursor

  for (var i=0; i<rango_limpiar.length;i++){
    Hoja_Activa.getRange(rango_limpiar[i]).clearContent();
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hello Friend, your Post has a problem and is written in a different Language than the expected on the Site; I recommend that you translate it into Spanish.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0):

El concepto de celda activa es otro, a lo que te estás refiriendo no se menciona en la documentación en la ayuda de los Editores de Google ni en la documentación de Google Apps Script.

Una celda activa es una celda que está resaltada con una línea gruesa. Un rango activo está resaltado con una línea delgada y sus celdas con excepción de la celda activa tienen un sombreado.

Al concepto que te estas refiriendo podríamos llamarle celda en modo de edición. No es posible quitar el modo de edición a una celda usando Google Apps Script. Lo mejor que puedes hacer es que la función sea llamada por medio de un menú ya que esto provocará la salida del modo de edición de la celda.

Comment: Muchas gracias, intentaré con esta opción