# ¿Es posible presionar ENTER desde Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy tratando de quitar el foco de edición a una celda, pero no existe esta instrucción en Apps Script.

La solución que se me ocurre es presionar ENTER desde el código.

¿Es posible presionar esta tecla desde Apps Script?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Si lo que necesitas es proteger una celda, este articulo que puede ser útil.  https://support.google.com/docs/thread/32422214/%C2%BFse-puede-bloquear-el-ingreso-de-datos-en-un-rango-celda-luego-de-ingresar-1-dato?hl=es

Comment: No, no necesito proteger celdas, necesito saber si es posible presionar enter desde el código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es posible.

Google Apps Script no puede "hacer click" "presionar enter" ni ninguna acción sobre la interfaz de usuario de Google Sheets.

La alternativa podría ser desarrollar una extensión de navegador o usar alguna herramienta de automatización que se instale en la computadora del usuario.

Relacionado

- [Desactivar celda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/553554/65)